# Reading and writing Hippo content

Tags: hippocms

What is the best way to read and write Hippo content programmaticaly? I want to build a migration tool that writes some pages and binary files to Hippo. I am now using the JCR API to create nodes in the repo, is there any better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:
http://import-tool.forge.onehippo.org/

(you can checkout source code and use it as a reference if needed)

Another one you could check is:
https://forge.onehippo.org/svn/restimporter/ 
(no documentation other than:
https://forge.onehippo.org/svn/restimporter/trunk/README.txt
)

hth

Comment: Thanks, i am going to have a look at that.